# Turn off automatic quote insertion in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp-classic, double-quotes

I am editing a huge number of legacy ASP pages that have been converted over to C#. One problem is that the HTML attributes need to be adjusted to correct some double quote problems.

My problem is that when I add a double quote VS dutifully inserts the closing quote in the wrong place.  I then need to go an delete that quote and enter the closing quote.  I also have to watch that when I insert the closing quote it does not throw in another extra quote.

I googled for a solution, I am sure it is easy to turn off.  But I could not find the right keywords to suss it out.

Comment: Has this feature ever been anything other than an annoyance to anyone?

Comment: No, the worst thing ever been thought

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 2 options I'm aware of which control the insertion of the double quotes for ASPX pages.

- Tools -> Options
- Text Editor -> HTML -> Formatting

Under the Automatic Formatting Options try toggling the following options

[image: Dialog Example]

I have both of these disabled and don't see the issue you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for the data point, I had already seen those but I still have the behavior I described.  It appears to be independent of those settings, that is why I am so puzzled.

Comment: Turns out it was ReSharper that was doing it!  So know I have to go hide my head for incorrectly assigning blame...  But that also hints to why my google search was failing to turn up anything useful.  I'll award you the green check-mark for pointing me in the right direction.