# How to prevent/disable visual studio auto correct of quotes after href when editing views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Have an annoying visual studio auto-complete behavior.

When editing an MVC view (cshtml) when typing href= Visual studio will autocomplete to "help me out" by auto completing the quotes, for example href="".  The problem is with MVC the majority of my links are generated dynamically using @Url.Action(...).

If there a way to control this auto editing?  A minor thing but it disrupt my flow every single time, enough that I posted the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just add Url.Action inside quotes. Like `href="@Url.Action(...)"`.

Or if you want to disable automatic quotes look here [Turn off automatic quote insertion in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620125/turn-off-automatic-quote-insertion-in-visual-studio-2010) is the same in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Adding the Url.Action with double quotes is the way to generate correct HTML markup, else you get a anchor tag that looks like `<a href=/Controller/Action>Link</a>` which is not syntactically valid

Comment: @Tommy it appear both href=@Url.Action(...) and href="@Url(...).Action" produce the same html.  MVC is "fixing" up the quote tags regardless.  It was just a bad assumption onmy part.  Since href=@Url.Action(...) produces valid html I assumed that adding quotes would end up with double quotation but that isn't the case.

Comment: @Jerney Novak Seems silly but I assumed that would produce invalid html but that isn't the case. Answer accepted.